# How exactly does django validates its cookie?

Tags: django, cookies, django-authentication, django-sessions

I was reading up on cookie validation and came across the question of how exactly does Django validates its cookie?

If I remember correctly, Django stores session id in the cookie for later use. Does that mean that anyone who fakes the cookie will be able to use arbitrary session data?

Comment: Cookies aren't supposed to be faked, and whoever can steal them can login as you. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking. Now, you ask "How Django validates its cookie"? You mean how Django verifies that the cookie ... what? I.e. what do you mean by "validates"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation itself is damn simple: against the data in in the session backend. As you can see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L67), the data you receive in a cookie comes from your session, `session_key` attribute. Where it is being stored depends on your session backend, by default it's the database.

1. It is impossible to "fake" a cookie. Unless someone stole your `SECRET_KEY`. More detailed info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions).
2. If someone steals a cookie from a client, the thief can use the client's session till it expires. You cannot prevent it. If you are aware of such a case, the client's password needs to be changed ASAP, as it will lead to invalidation of ther user's existing sessions (starting from Django 1.10).

Upd: your question made me curious whether the session backend actually stores the value as is... Figures, it does. *(I got also impressed there's pgAdmin for Windows)*
[image]